# Howto do autocomplete with Symfony3 AJAX and Chosen2

Tags: ajax, symfony, jquery-select2

Hi and thanks for helping me, English is not my first language, sorry in advance. :)

When selecting the selectbox I get the notification "no results found", but when I look at the result in the developer toolbar I see that I receive a complete JSON.

How can I match a single value instead of getting the whole JSON?

**JSON result:**

```
["Descent: Journeys in the Dark (Second Edition)","Dominion","Ascension","Star wars LCG","Magic: The
 Gathering  Duel Decks Anthology"]
```

The script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $('select').select2({
         placeholder: 'Select an item',
         ajax: {
             url: '{{ path('user_games_json') }}', //url to the json data
             dataType: 'json',
             delay: 250,
             processResults: function (data) {
                 return {
                     results: data
                 };
             },
             cache: true
         }
     });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the data from server by ajax request you can use [Select2 Bundle](https://github.com/tetranz/select2entity-bundle)  i'm using it in my  projects it's one of the best  bundle you can use to make auto complete functionality .